# Connecting a groovy application to SQL server Express

Tags: grails, jdbc, datasource, sql-server-express

I was following the tutorial below but there must be some significant steps where knowledge, that I don't have, is being assumed.

http://padcom13.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/setting-up-sql-server-2008-express-to.html

below is the setup in my datasource.groovy

```
username = "sa"
password = ""
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Sandpit"
driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
```

and below is the error popping up on run app command

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: 
Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' 
while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: 
Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is 
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
```

Been working on this a couple of days without seeing my app run..... any advice?

Comment: Have you copied `sqljdbc4.jar` into your lib folder?

Comment: Yep, and configured the IDE build path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause is `Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'`

That's because your driver is missing in the classpath. In the case of SQL Server you need to copy the jar to the lib folder.

In other cases like MySQL you can declare as a maven dependency.

Comment: So very close, thank you, the thing starts up again but I am getting a warning Error WARNING: Specified dependency definition runtime(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver) is invalid! Skipping..

Comment: And none of the new information added has been committed to the corresponding table static mapping = {
  table 'MusicCatalogue'
      cache true
  id column: 'ID'
  artist column: 'ARTIST'
  track column: 'TRACK'
  album column: 'ALBUM'
}

Comment: Ok, edited and removed the maven dependecy, since sql server is not available in this case. Just copy the jar to the lib folder.

Comment: Sorry, allow me to correct myself. It is functioning, you're right. BUT not persisting information to the database. Is there something inaccurate about my URL setup???

Comment: OH YOU'RE AWESOME! I worked out I was being an idiot and had multiple URLs in my datasource, so it was still pointing to memory. All sorted all working. Would vote you up if I had the reputation. Thanks

Comment: ummmmmm hate to say this but, I could really do with a hand again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559296/error-when-attempting-grails-start-up-following-jdbc-setup

Answer (score 0):

We are doing the same thing like you.
Therefor, we have the sqljdbc.jar in our /lib -directory.

In our DataSource.groovy we have then:

```
dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
username = "dbo"
driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://devdb02:1433;databaseName=my_database;"
```

I remember that just the .jar is not enough, I think you need to install a small part into your windows/unix-directory e.g. from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

(that's also needed if you maybe use PHP with MSSQL)

Comment: The Jar is in place and the classpath is configured both in windows and the ide specific variables for the project. Any help would really be appreciated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559296/error-when-attempting-grails-start-up-following-jdbc-setup