# Error when attempting Grails start up, following JDBC setup

Tags: grails, jdbc, groovy, datasource, sql-server-express

There is a potential that I should be reusing an existing question of mine. 
[Connecting a groovy application to SQL server Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523050/connecting-a-groovy-application-to-sql-server-express/14523114#comment20251270_14523114)

BUT this seems to be a bit different. The question was brought up while configuring a test application, now I am doing the real thing and this is the time that it goes really wrong.

As you can see the Jar file is in my lib and classpath

[image: jdbc shown in ggts]

my datasource is configured as below (pretty much a copy paste job from my working example)

```
dataSource {
username = "sa"
password = "password"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TimeTracker"
driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
```

and I am getting the following error on grails run-app, any advice would be welcomed with open arms

```
Error 2013-01-27 16:09:06,772 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  
- Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' 
while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 
'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: 
Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; 
nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 
'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' 
while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: 
Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is 
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 
'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
```

Comment: To check you can inject classLoader to your bootstrap using "def classLoader" and try def driverClass =  Class.forName('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver', true, classLoader). If class is not returned, it means it is not in the classpath. Also check if specified class is in your version of jdbc driver jar.

Comment: I am afraid the error remains, and as above because I have already tested this using another simpler application, using the same JDBC .jar, the driver definitely exists. Really need help on this I am really stuck

Comment: Create a WAR using 'grails war' command and check if lib is added to the file. Also did you try Class.forName() as described previously?

Answer (score 3):

Do `grails --refresh-dependencies compile` one more time, and it will be good to go.

If the problem still persists, here's additional information to double checking:

1. Check if there's whitespace in your path. Grails does not work well if the path contains whitespace characters, especially on Windows.
2. Check your Grails installation, and make sure it's working for a simple app.
3. Check if your ivy cache (`under ~/.grails/` or `c:\<your home>\.grails`) is healthy. If not, just delete it and Grails will recreate a new ivy cache for you.
4. If no. 1-3 couldn't help, delete `~/.grails` or `c:\<your home>\.grails` to clean everything releated to Grails, and start over.

Comment: I am just doing it right now and it's working fine. You may be trying it 1. with command line outside Eclipse. 2. re-check if the jar file is not corrupted. My sqljdbc4.jar is 584,207 bytes.

Comment: I executing using the IDE (using GGTS, an eclipse derivative) and it works fine on a previous application. and second I checked the jar file and it's fine, it's the exact size as the jar in the application that is working fine and the same size having downloaded and unzipped again.

Comment: In a further update I can confirm that the datasource.groovy file is fine, this has been tested in the previous application and it finds the location fine.

Comment: I have checked all you said, I have rebuilt the classpath 3 times, I have removed all other instances in my workspace, the error still exists.

Comment: This is why I asked you to test outside Eclipse. Just try to see if it's working normally without the IDE.

Comment: OK, then try a working app of mine, http://goo.gl/3Hzs4 to see if it's working for you.

Comment: You're using 2.2.0 to my 2.1.1 would that make an impact?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23507/discussion-between-chanwit-and-user1854751)

Comment: after our chat, it has unfortunately broken the application further, Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : null
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument

Comment: I have movement now, you were right my grails version had become corrupted now getting errors associated to sql and my code. fingers crossed and a few hours more work I may get somewhere

Comment: Working, thank you for your help, wouldn't have gotten there without you.

Comment: Glad it's working. Do not forget to share your steps that solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue to this lay largely with my version of Grails, specifically the IVY files that had been built up over time...... I pretty much have been annihilating this project since day one and each project you run in grails creates it's own config files in your home grails directory. Mine had become horribly corrupted after months of abuse.

By renaming the folder and downloading my version of grails to the expected directory again the application files were created fresh and the application was immediately able to find the SQL JDBC jar.

I owe finding this solution to  [ChanWit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60903/chanwit) without whom I think I would have had a mental breakdown.